# Closure of the polynomials in $\sin x$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

What is the closure in $C[0,\pi]$ of the family of polynomials of the form
$$
a_0+a_1\sin x+a_2\sin^2x+\cdots+a_k\sin^k x
$$
I've already proven that they are dense in $C[0,1]$, so their closure in this set is $C[0,1]$, but now I need to find its closure in $C[0,\pi]$. Are they dense here as well?

Comment: $[0,\pi]$ or $[0,1]?$

Comment: @zhw. I've edited the post. I'm asking for $[0,\pi]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. Every function in the closure satisfies $f(\pi -x)=f(x)$.

Applying Stone-Weierstrass Theorem we see that polynomials in $\sin x$ are dense in $C[0,\pi /2]$. Now it is trivial to see that the closure of polynomials in $\sin x$ on $C[0,\pi ]$ is precisely all continuous functions $f$ satisfying $f(\pi -x)=f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: So what would the closure be? The family itself?

Comment: The closure is precisely $\{f: C[0,\pi]: f(x-\pi)=f(x)\}$ for all $x$. @maria221

Comment: @maria221 I have edited the answer.

Comment: How can I prove that ${f:C[0,π]:f(x−π)=f(x)}$ is in the closure of the polynomials in sin$x$?

Comment: If you prove that such a function can be approximated uniformly on $[0,\pi/2]$ it would automatically give you an approximation on $[0,\pi]$. For $[0,\pi/2]$ apply S-W theorem. @maria221

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Each of those polynomials satisfies $p(0)=p(\pi).$